# Show a div next to the element using onmouseover?

Tags: css, onmouseover

I have a div, like this:

```
<div id="div1" name="div1" style="display:none;">
    hello world
</div>
```

Thats on the bottom of my page. Now, when putting the mouse on an image, I want to show that div below the image. The problem is, I have 10 images next to each other and the div should be displayed below each of them dynamically, meaning putting the mouse on image 6 should display the div below image 6.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to use jQuery. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: Well, the hiding and showing is not the problem. I dont know how to display it below the element the mouse is over.

Comment: Do you want to move the div inside the DOM or do you want to use CSS position properties?

Comment: You can do that setting position to your elements... you'll need a new container to every "pair" of image and div. than you'll set the container to position: relative; and every div to position: absolute;

Comment: I dont really care to be honest, as long as it works :).

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approach if you want to use jQuery and want to move the div inside your DOM:

```
$(function() {
    var div1 = $('#div1').remove();
    $('img')
        .bind('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).parent().append(div1);
        })
        .bind('mouseleave', function() {
            div1.remove();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I use that script?

Comment: Well, this is Javascript. Put it into script tags, load a jQuery library and reload the page...

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by only CSS here is an working example:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


    <style>

        *                   { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body                { font: 12px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; }

        img                 {width: 125px;}
        #page-wrap          { width: 125px; margin: 62px auto; }

        h1                  { font-size: 30px; letter-spacing: -1px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; } 

        .people             { position: relative; width: 125px;} 
        a                   { text-decoration: none; color: #222; display: block; outline: none; padding: 5px; }
        a img               { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
        a .name             { font: 12px Georgia, Serif; width: 125px; display: none;}
        a:hover .name       { color: #900; font-weight: bold; position: relative; display: block;} 
        a:hover img         { border: 1px solid #000; margin: 0px; }
        a .photo            { display: block; position: absolute; width: 125px; height: 125px; }
        #toby .photo        { top: 0; left: 0; position: relative;}

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">

        <div class="people">

            <a href="#toby" id="toby">
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="http://www.style-makeover-hq.com/images/what-is-my-face-shape-and-what-is-the-best-haircut-for-it-21276689.jpg" alt="Toby Pic" />
                </div>
                <div class="name">Toby Yong<br />
                    Toby Young joins the fifth season of Top Chef to lend his culinary expertise to the judges table.
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek4Ej/

Code is based on this article: http://css-tricks.com/remote-linking/

- you can easily add more images with this effect on page or apply any style to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ipurix/6/edit)

```
$(function() {

  $("#main").on("hover",".img img", function(){

    pos = $(this).offset();
    $(".box").css({"left":pos.left,"top":(pos.top + $(this).height())});
   $(".box").show();

  });


});
```